# gnuplot - operating on a two digit column

Tags: gnuplot

I'm trying to operate on a column prior to its plotting. This is the line I'm having issues with:

```
plot campo1 u 1:($22*0.05)
```

where `campo1` is the path to the file. The problem is that `gnuplot` recognizes `$22` **not** as column `22` but as column `2` multiplied by `2*0.05`.

How can I tell `gnuplot` to use column `22` in the operation?

Comment: forgot the exact syntax, but did you try ${22} or $(22) instead?

Comment: Yes, I've tried them both. I've also tried `($22)`, `{$22}`, `$'22'`, `$"22"`, `'$22'` and `"$22"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the right syntax, the command is: `\$22`

Answer (score 0):

Try `plot campo1 u 1:(0.05*$22)` instead

Comment: Thanks but that wasn't helpful either. I finally found the correct syntax so I added my own answer. Cheers.